# How to get the boundaries of an area after scale/translate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, zooming

I have a simple **WPF** interface with two panels. In the right one, I have two sliders which I use to scale and move a simple shape on the left panel.

I also have a **MouseMove** event that runs when I move the cursor over the shape.

When I use the slider to translate/scale the shape and then move the mouse cursor to get the mouse position I get the right results which are different for before and after the scale/transform. (as shown in the figures below).

What I want to do is how can I get the boundaries of the area (colored azure) after each transformation.

[image]

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="GUI.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Zoom Slider" Height="300" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="Azure" x:Name="_window" MouseMove="_window_MouseMove">
        <Canvas x:Name="_c" Width="100" Height="100" 
                Background="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=_zoomSlider, Path=Value}" 
                                    ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=_zoomSlider, Path=Value}"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ElementName=_panSlider, Path=Value}"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        </Canvas>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Background="Aquamarine" Grid.Column="1">
            <Slider x:Name="_zoomSlider" 
                    Maximum="2" Minimum="0.5" Value="1" 
                    Width="200"/>
            <Slider x:Name="_panSlider" 
                    Maximum="100" Minimum="-100" Value="0" 
                    Width="200"/>            
            <Label x:Name="_mousePosition">Mouse Position</Label>
            <Label x:Name="_boundaries">Boundaries</Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace GUI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void _window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _mousePosition.Content = (Math.Round(Mouse.GetPosition(_c).X)).ToString()
                + ", "
                + (Math.Round(Mouse.GetPosition(_c).Y)).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be asking for this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.transformtovisual(v=vs.95).aspx

```
// Return the general transform for the specified visual object.
GeneralTransform generalTransform1 = myStackPanel.TransformToVisual(myTextBlock);

// Retrieve the point value relative to the child.
Point currentPoint = generalTransform1.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Comment: It doesn't explain how to use it.

Comment: You downvoted my answer because I didnt write down for you how to implement it in your example? Have you tried googing that method? How about you go to google.com and type in how to transformtovisual in wpf? I know its alot work, right. I posted you an example in my answer.

Comment: No, I didn't downvote your answer I didn't upvote it either. Cause I really didn't know what to do with the answer. Yes, I googled a lot regarding this, but honestly I didn't find a suitable solution.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the logic behind Point(0,0) in your code? Thanks.

Comment: the textblock is a visual and lets say its 100 x 20 big. that means there are 100 pixels on xaxis and 20 pixels on yaxis. now lets follow that thought and we come up with point(0,0) being the zero point. now you take the zero point of your textblock and you transform it to stackpanel. if the textblock is fifth item in stackpanel the result will be pint(0, 100) when transformed to stackpanel.

Comment: Thank you so much. The point(0,0) gets the coordinate relative to top left corner of the element, right? What if I wanted for example the bottom right corner? Should I use Point(100,100) in my case?

Comment: Right, now you got it ;)